# How to remove Self Hosted Integration Runtime from VM?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-data-factory

I have a Self hosted IR in a VM that is connected to an IR in ADF and that works fine. However, I want to connect a different IR to the VM. I just can't seem to find a way to remove integration of the existing IR in Microsoft Integration Runtime Configuration Manager.

I could always delete the IR from the ADF and maybe it reflects on the VM. But I am not sure if this would work and don't want to risk breaking the system.

The git config in the ADF is pointing to 2 ADF resources. The IR connects on the first one(where IR was created from portal). The 2nd ADF was created later and whose git was pointing to the same repo as 1st one. When I start the VM, the IR says Running in 1st one but 'Failed to get status' in 2nd one.

1. Is it possible to safely uninstall the IR on VM, create a new IR on 2nd ADF and integrate that? if yes, how? Or,
2. Somehow make the IR in VM to point to 2nd ADF. I can't find how to do that either.

Edit - I want to delete 1st ADF and just have the 2nd one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to uninstall the IR on VM, just create a shared self-hosted integration runtime for your second ADF, then both of them can access the data on VM. You can configure is on Portal:

[image]

For more details, please ref: [Create a shared self-hosted integration runtime in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-shared-self-hosted-integration-runtime-powershell):

- This guide shows you how to create a shared self-hosted integration
  runtime in Azure Data Factory. Then you can use the shared
  self-hosted integration runtime in another data factory.

One IR only can be register one time, if need want to remove it on VM, we need to do like this:

1. Stop the service first.
2. Stop and delete the runtime on Azure.
3. Connect to the VM an uninstall the program on Control Panel.

That's the way to safely uninstall the IR on VM.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that information. I had used that as a stop gap. I made an edit to the question. The 1st ADF needs to be deleted.

Comment: @YashTamakuwalas stop the IR on Azure and then uninstall it on VM. Can you connect to the VM?

Comment: Yes, I can connect to the VM. Do you mean uninstalling the Configuration Manager? Because I dont see any way to uninstall IR. Just start and Stop service.

Comment: @YashTamakuwala yeah, firstly stop the service, then please go to the control panel to uninstall the whole Microsoft integration runtime program. Also delete it on Portal.

Comment: Yes, that worked. This is quite weird and misleading. Theres no way to disconnect. Need to uninstall the entire program. Can you pls edit your answer accordingly, I can accept it.

Comment: @YashTamakuwala sure,  I have done. Thank you  very much!